# Поэлементный доступ к элементам строки в С

Tags: c, массивы, строки

Принемаю на вход число, которое надо преобразовать в строку Си. Делаю это с помощью snprintf(). Надо проделать некоторые преобразования с каждым числовым символом (элементом) этой строки. И вот проблема: я не знаю, как обращатся к каждому элементу по отдельности в строке Си. Вот пример кода, где я бы хотел проверить это. Переменная element получает весь набор элементов строки после пятого. Я бы хотел получить только один пятый символ. Подскажите, как правильно это сделать?

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(){

    long number = GetLongLong();
    char str[17];
    int size = 0;
    size = snprintf(str, 17, "%ld", number);
    char* n = str;
    int element = atoi(&n[4]);
    printf("%d\n", element);

    return 0;
}
```

Вот пример работы програмы:

```
vovaka:~/workspace/pset2 $ make credit.c credit
make: Nothing to be done for `credit.c'.
clang -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror    credit.c  -lcs50 -lm -o credit
vovaka:~/workspace/pset2 $ ./credit
21454265
4265
```

В переменную записалось число 4264, а мне надо только 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант 1:

```
char tmp[2] = {0};
tmp[0] = n[4];
int element = atoi(tmp);
```

Вариант 2:

```
int element = n[4] - '0';
```

Comment: можешь обьяснить, что происходит во втором варианте?

Comment: @VovaPolischuck символы цифр в ascii идут по порядку. '0' имеет код 48, '9' - 57 соответственно. Вычитая из кода любой цифры код '0', получается числовое представление исходной цифры.

Например у вас есть '5'. Код '5'  == 53.
'5' - '0' == 53 - 48 == 5

Но нужно быть аккуратным. Если на вход подать не цифровой символ, то получится белеберда.

Answer (score 0):

Оператор [] служит для доступа к элементам массива. Например `n[3] = 'A';` запишет в 4-й элемент букву A